# Simple Java web app code

Tags: java, http, jsp

I wanted to work on `HttpSessions` and JSP.

This is the view I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <c:out value="All available products:"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <c:forEach items="${applicationScope.allProducts}" var="product">
        <c:out value="${product}"/>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/shop?addProductbyName=<c:out  value="${product}"/>">Add to basket</a>
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <br/>
    Currently your cart contains these items dude:
    <br/>

    <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.cart}" var="product">
        <c:out value="${product.key}"/>
        &nbsp;
        <c:out value="${product.value}"/>
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Servlet:

```
package com.tugay;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * User: koraytugay
 * Date: 20/07/14
 * Time: 18:07
 */

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/shop", name = "shoppingServlet")
public class ShopServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        if (getServletContext().getAttribute("allProducts") == null) {
            getServletContext().setAttribute("allProducts", Database.getAllProducts());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, Integer> cart = doSessionStuff(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        String addProductbyName = httpServletRequest.getParameter("addProductbyName");
        if (addProductbyName != null) {
            if (cart.get(addProductbyName) == null) {
                cart.put(addProductbyName, 0);
            }
            cart.put(addProductbyName, cart.get(addProductbyName) + 1);
        }

        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/shopping.jsp");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, Integer> doSessionStuff(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
        Map<String, Integer> cartMap = null;
        if (session.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
            cartMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            session.setAttribute("cart", cartMap);
        }
        cartMap = (Map<String, Integer>) session.getAttribute("cart");
        return cartMap;
    }
}
```

And the "Mock" Db:

```
package com.tugay;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * User: koraytugay
 * Date: 20/07/14
 * Time: 17:58
 */
public class Database {

    private static HashMap<Integer,String> products = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    static {

        products.put(1,"Table");
        products.put(2,"Sofa");
        products.put(3,"Chair");
        products.put(4,"Window");

    }

    public static List<String> getAllProducts() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(products.values());
    }

}
```

This is what my page looks like:

[image]

If anyone wants to review this, they are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Interfaces vs implementations

Always use interfaces in declarations, not implementations. Instead of:

> ```
>  private static HashMap<Integer,String> products = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
> ```

Do like this:

```
private static Map<Integer,String> products = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

---

#### doSessionStuff

The `httpServletResponse` parameter is unused, so drop it.

No need to initialize `cartMap` to `null`, as you will assign to it anyway. Actually you don't need that local variable at all, you could simplify the method without it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Map<String, Integer> doSessionStuff(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
        session.setAttribute("cart", new HashMap<String, Integer>());
    }
    return (Map<String, Integer>) session.getAttribute("cart");
}
```

#### doGet

You only use the `cart` variable if `addProductbyName != null`, so it would be better to move it inside the `if` block.

It's a bit awkward to do `cart.put(addProductbyName, 0);` and then again `cart.put(addProductbyName, cart.get(addProductbyName) + 1);`. And you are doing `cart.get(addProductbyName)` multiple times.

The `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is also unnecessary for this method, as there are no unchecked casts.

The method would be cleaner like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String addProductbyName = httpServletRequest.getParameter("addProductbyName");
    if (addProductbyName != null) {
        Map<String, Integer> cart = doSessionStuff(httpServletRequest);
        Integer count = cart.get(addProductbyName);
        if (count == null) {
            cart.put(addProductbyName, 1);
        } else {
            cart.put(addProductbyName, count + 1);
        }
    }

    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/shopping.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the JSP, there are a couple areas where you are inconsistant in your style.  For example, you are outputting strings via

```
<c:out value="All available products:"/>
```

vs

```
  Currently your cart contains these items dude:
```

Also, you are mixing/matching c:out and EL string interpolation in your url construction here.  You can simplify it:

```
<a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/shop?addProductbyName=${product}"/>">Add to basket</a>
```

Comment: So this is not required: <c:out  value="${product}" ?

Comment: Nope, just like you are able to add the contextPath in the same way.

Comment: Is there any better way to make this link only with <c:url and maybe c:param ?

Comment: It is quite important to stress the difference between using `c:out` or not. Always use `c:out` for dynamic data, @KorayTugay. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291031/jsp-cout-tag